# How to make Scipy solve this optimization problem?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-algebra

I want to solve this optimization problem using Scipy

```
min tr(KL)
s.t K is PSD
```

tr: trace.

s.t: such that.

PSD: positive semi-definite

The minimization is over K, while L is given.

Is there a solver for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: Do you have additional restrictions on L?  Otherwise, there exist matrices L such that tr(KL) has no lower bound over all PSD K.